# backup MMS in android 1.6

Tags: backup, mms, sony-ericsson-xperia-x10, 1.6-donut

I know there are many duplicates, but unfortunately the specifications on every software proposed to do it are very poor about

- wether they support VERY OLD android versions
- and wether they will backup MMS, not only SMS

I have android 1.6 on an old phone (Xperia X10), it is full of MMS (I already extracted all the SMS with myphoneexplorer), full of story, and if I update it to android 2.0...I will lose all this. I guess with the ADB driver I have access to almost all the phone memory, so can anyone tell me if there is a way to backup all the MMS, with their metadata (who sent them, when), from my old android 1.6?

It's here, somewhere in the phone memory, but how do I access it and backup everything...if possible in a readable format (even by the software, to check by myself that it has indeed copied the desired data!)?

The search is very hard, I thought I had found it with "Message Sync"...until I understood this app is only for android 2.1 or later. Always 2.something!

Thank you very much, it would help me a lot!

Answer (score 3):

[SMS Backup +](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zegoggles.smssync) reports to work on Android 1.5 and above and it backs up MMS. It pushes everything to your GMail account under a defined label. I've been using it for a while and it's very good.